# Code to retrieve selected country for shipping address from Magento user details

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

How would I retrieve this information from a users details when they save their account?
I found a tutorial online and followed that to build an observer for the customer before save event (I'm not sure this is the correct event to observe, but maybe!).

http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/automatically-set-magento-customer-group

But how do I get the value the user has selected as the country of their shipping address?

The idea here is to assign a customer into a customer group based on their shipping address (country).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question is redundant in my scenario as Magento's tax classes achieve what I was trying to work out here.
Tax based on shipping address :-)